Why is my Liftmaster 8500 only opening partway?
When I open the garage door in the morning, it only goes up about 3 inches, sometimes not at all. I have to keep pressing the remote until it finally goes up. It works fine the rest of the day until the next morning when the same thing happens.

What happens when it stops? Any blinking lights, sounds, or other feedback? Is the door balanced when disconnected? Do all the springs and cables look ok? Please revise to add detail. Take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

The opener will not operate if the door is too heavy. Disconnect the lift arm from the carrier and try to lift the door manually.  If it is difficult for you to lift with one arm, it is too heavy and needs the assistance increased.  try this and report back by adding the info into your original question.

For clarity, "assistance" refers to spring tension, not opener force.
